# How does one solve this kind of equation: $3^x=x+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, newton-raphson, lambert-w

How does one solve this kind of equation: $$3^x=x+3$$

I tried playing around with logs but it didn't get me anywhere.
I plotted the two functions $f(x)=3^x$ and $g(x)=x+3$ on a graph to estimate the point of intersection but how do I solve it?

Comment: Try taking $\log_3$ both sides...

Comment: use a numerical method e.g. the Newton-Raphson method

Comment: @Derek: Root finding numerical method is typically the way - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: Similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068498/solve-for-x-both-2-values-as-plotted-on-graph

Answer (score 2):

You've to use the Product log function (when you don't want it the 'numerical method' way):

$$y^x=x+y\Longleftrightarrow x=-\frac{\text{W}_n\left(-\frac{\ln(y)}{y^y}\right)+y\ln(y)}{\ln(y)}$$

Where $\text{W}_k(z)$ is the analytic continuation of the product log funtion and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

When $y=3$, we've the following real solutions:

- $$x=-\frac{\text{W}\left(-\frac{\ln(3)}{27}\right)+3\ln(3)}{\ln(3)}\approx-2.96136$$
- $$x=-\frac{\text{W}_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln(3)}{27}\right)+3\ln(3)}{\ln(3)}\approx1.33509$$

Comment: This looks impressive Jan but I'm not familiar with this method. I found the Newton-Raphson method sufficient. Cheers

Comment: @Derek I understand, but I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using the Newton-Raphson method.

$$f(x)=3^x-x-3$$

$$f'(x)=3^xln3-1$$

$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$

Getting first estimates from my graph:
$$Let: x_{1}=2$$
$$x_{2}=1.5499$$
$$x_{3}=1.3632$$
$$x_{4}=1.3356$$
$$x_{5}=1.3351$$
$$x=1.3 (1dp)$$

And then the second point of intersection:
$$Let: x_{1}=-1$$
$$x_{2}=-3.630$$
$$x_{3}=-2.968$$
$$x_{4}=-2.961$$
$$x=-3.0 (1dp)$$

Thanks all.

Comment: There is one more intersection.

Comment: Thanks Arbuja. I should have noticed that. I've included the second solution. Thanks.