# Solve for $x$ (both 2 values as plotted on graph):

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, roots, lambert-w

find a way to solve for x:
     $$ 2^x = x + 5$$

You can easily see one of the values is $3$.
If you plot this in a graph, with $y=2^x$ and $y=x+5$,
you'll see it has 2 values.
If, in a calculator like casio fx-991E series, PLUS perhaps,
you plunk in $2^x=x+5$ and hit solve (shift + calc),
you'll get the other value, as the calculator solves from left to right.

But the thing is to find a manual, universal way to solve it

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lambert W-Function?

Comment: Similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810003/how-does-one-solve-this-kind-of-equation-3x-x3

Answer (score 0):

observe that for $2^x\gt x+5$ for$x\ge 4$

which follows by induction

again $2^x\lt x+5$ for $x\lt 2$

which again follows by induction

so $2\lt x\lt 4$

i think it would be helpful!!!

Comment: It's not true that $2^x \leq x + 5$ for all $x \leq 2$.  As $x \to -\infty$, $2^x \to 0$ but $x + 4 \to -\infty$.

Comment: induction with real numbers?

Comment: thanks i had mistypped that!!!

Comment: you can prove it very easily

Comment: observe decrease & increase in both sides

Comment: It's still false.  Try $x = -6$.  $2^{x} = 1/64 > -1 = x + 5$